# Django generates slow queries for OR clause (left outer join instead of union)

Tags: mysql, django, performance, left-join, union

I have the following two models

```
class Video(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    videos = models.ManyToManyField('Video')
```

Now I make the following queryset and print its query

```
qs = Video.objects.filter(Q(store__name="blockbuster") | Q(pk__in=[1,2,3,4]))
print qs.query
```

The following query is generated.

```
SELECT `video`.`id`, `video`.`name`,  
FROM `video` LEFT OUTER JOIN `store` ON (`store`.`video_id` = `video`.`id`) 
WHERE (`store`.`name` = "blockbuster"  OR `video`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4))
```

When I do an explain plan on this query, mysql does a full table scan on the video table, despite adding every possible index. This is costing a me lot. How can I either force mysql to use an index or force django to use a `UNION ALL` which is faster instead of 'OR'?

Comment: Have you considered fetching two separate collections and then removing the collisions rather than using the Q()|Q()?

Answer (score 0):

Add an index for store_name,

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
```

EDIT:

can you document any existing indices via:

```
show index from video;
show index from store;
```

Comment: The OP says he has indexes but MySQL apparently is not using them.